Atlas Search across Enbedded Document and Root Document fields using Compound/Must
How do I perform a “Compound/Must” across EnbeddedDocument and RootDocument fields?
Ive create a playground for this issue im facing
https://search-playground.mongodb.com/tools/code-playground/snapshots/6728e35e406912c3e0e06912
Using the example I would like to search for “Big” and “Piano” across all searchable fields. Both values MUST exist. The search result should return the document with _id “101”, as “Big” exist in “PublisherName” and “Piano” exist in “Books.Title”.
Sample Document
{
    "_id": "101",
    "PublisherName": "Big book publishers",
    "PublisherAddress": "123 Mian Street",
    "Books": [
        {
            "_id": "6791913210",
            "Title": "Piano made simple",
            "Author": "John Bent"
        },
        {
            "_id": "6638200210",
            "Title": "Guitar made simple",
            "Author": "Kim Larry"
        }
    ]
}

Search Index
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "Books": {
        "dynamic": false,
        "fields": {
          "Author": {
            "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Title": {
            "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "type": "embeddedDocuments"
      },
      "PublisherAddress": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "PublisherName": {
        "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}

My Sample search which does not work (when embeddedDocument is added)
[
    {
        "$search": {
            "index": "default",
            "compound": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "query": "Big",
                            "path": [
                                "PublisherName",
                                "PublisherAddress"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "query": "Piano",
                            "path": [
                                "PublisherName",
                                "PublisherAddress"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "embeddedDocument": {
                            "operator": {
                                "text": {
                                    "query": "Big",
                                    "path": [
                                        "Books.Title",
                                        "Books.Author"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "text": {
                                    "query": "Piano",
                                    "path": [
                                        "Books.Title",
                                        "Books.Author"
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            "path": "Books"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]


My post was answered in the Mongo DB Community Forum.
This issue was solved by using the below changes to the Search Index and Search Aggregation
Payground with solution
https://search-playground.mongodb.com/tools/code-playground/snapshots/672a21d77816de283aa55341
Search Index

Can be defined without the "embeddedDocuments" as its actually not used for this search.
 {
  "mappings": {
      "dynamic": false,
      "fields": {
          "Books": [
              {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "type": "embeddedDocuments",
                  "fields": {
                      "Author": {
                          "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      "Title": {
                          "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
                          "type": "string"
                      }
                  }
              },
              {
                  "dynamic": false,
                  "type": "document",
                  "fields": {
                      "Author": {
                          "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      "Title": {
                          "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
                          "type": "string"
                      }
                  }
              }
          ],
          "PublisherAddress": {
              "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
              "type": "string"
          },
          "PublisherName": {
              "analyzer": "lucene.standard",
              "type": "string"
          }
      }
  }

}


Search Aggregation
[
    {
        "$search": {
            "index": "default",
            "compound": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "query": "Big",
                            "path": [
                                "PublisherName",
                                "PublisherAddress"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "query": "Piano",
                            "path": [
                                "Books.Title",
                                "Books.Author"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]

